# Edges do not appear using gastex and drawedge

Tags: diagrams, auto-pst-pdf, ps

I have a mysterious edge disappearance with the following code (using package `gastex`, that itself uses `ps` and `auto-pst-pdf`):

```
\begin{center}
\unitlength=4pt
\begin{picture}(16,19)(0,-3)\nullfont
    \gasset{Nframe=n,Nw=4,Nh=4,Nmr=2,curvedepth=0}\small
    \node[Nw=7](F)(0,13){$F(A)$}
    \node(M)(8,0){$M$}
    \node(N)(16,13){$N$}
    \drawedge[ELside=r](F,M){$\varphi$}
    \drawedge(F,N){$\alpha$}
    \drawedge(N,M){$\gamma$}
\end{picture}
\end{center}
```

The labels of the edges do appear at the correct places. On other computers it seems to work, since my coauthor sent a pdf with the correct picture using the same code, so it's probably my LaTeX library (I'm using texlive), but I get no errors or warnings in the log, so I'm lost.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If I run just latex, then I don't see the labels `\phi` and `\gamma`. However, if I convert the `dvi` to `ps`, then the labels appear. So it might be just a problem of the `dvi` viewer.

Comment: @gernot thanks ! I forgot to say; I'm compiling with pdflatex

Answer (score 1):

Change *pdflatex* compilation to *LaTeX* (OverLeaf) or use `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317115/gastex-figure-has-text-but-missing-all-graphical-elements).

Comment: I think it should be a comment.

Comment: But this is a solution; thus it could be an answer.